# Best way to replicate this in latex

Tags: equations, align, matrices

I am looking for a good way to replicate this in LaTeX:

[image]

Particularly, I want the brackets and the vertical bar to automatically resize when more constraints are added to the right. I am also curious if there is a preferred way of creating the column vector [X; a].

What I had so far was

```
$\text{epiAV@R}^\lambda_\alpha =$
\begin{equation}
    \left\{
    \begin{bmatrix}
        X\\
        a
    \end{bmatrix}
    \in  \mathbb{R}^{n+1}
    \middle|
    \parbox[c][][c]{4.5cm}{$\exists y_1\in \mathbb{R}^n_{\geq 0}$, $y_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n_{\geq 0}$,\\ $y_3 \in \mathbb{R} \colon y_1-y_2+y_3 1_n^\top=X$, $\lambda^\prime \pi^\top y_1 -\lambda \pi^\top y_2 + y_3 \leq a$}
    \right\}
\end{equation}
```

but I wasn't too happy with the hard coded parbox width.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Ok, out of curiosity, what field of science is this from, so I know in which direction not to go?

Comment: Risk averse optimization, in my case applied to the control of bioreactors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This requires `amsmath` and `amssymb`. Just like `\left` and `\right`, there is also a `\middle`-command which can be used to scale the bar in the middle.
I'm not sure whether using `\substack` is the nicest way to have the `[X;a]`-vector, but at least it reproduces the picture you sent.

```
\begin{align}
   &\text {epi AV@R}_{\alpha}^{\lambda}= \nonumber\\
   &\left\{
   [\substack{X\\a}]\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}
   \,\middle|\,
   \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
      $\exists y_{1} \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^{n}, y_{2} \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^{n},$ \\
      $y_{3} \in \mathbb{R} \colon y_{1}-y_{2}+y_{3} 1_{n}^{\top}=X$                        \\
      $\lambda^{\prime} \pi^{\top} y_{1}-\lambda \pi^{\top} y_{2}+y_{3} \leq a$
   \end{tabular}
   \right\}
\end{align}
```

[image]

Comment: The code would be a bit simpler with a`{matrix*}[l]` environment in the place of `{tabular}{@{]l@{}` .

Comment: There's no need for [`stackengine`](//ctan.org/pkg/stackengine) here.

Comment: Thanks @Werner, you are right. I will adapt my answer. I was sure that `\substack` needs `stackengine`, but obviously I was wrong.

Answer (score 5):

I propose a slightly simpler code, based on the `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX` from `mathtools` to define a `\set{1st argt ; 2nd argt}` command (requires also `xparse`), and the `matrix*` environment. The whole equation fits on a single line.

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\set}[1]\{\}{\setargs{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargs}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{;}}m}
{\setargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargsaux}{mm}
{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{#1}{\nonscript\,#1\nonscript\;\delimsize\vert\nonscript\;\allowbreak #2\nonscript\,}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \text{epi AV@R}_{\alpha}^{\lambda}=
   \set*{%
    \begin{bmatrix}X\\a \end{bmatrix} \in\mathbb{R}^{n+1} ;
   \begin{matrix*}[l]
      \exists y_{1} \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^{n}, y_{2} \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^{n}, \\
      y_{3} \in \mathbb{R} \colon y_{1}-y_{2}+y_{3} 1_{n}^{\top}=X \\
      \lambda^{\prime} \pi^{\top} y_{1}-\lambda \pi^{\top} y_{2}+y_{3} \leq a
   \end{matrix*}
   }
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @Sebastiano. Once more, I forgot to check whether everything looked normal…

Comment: It is a good answer...and otherwise your code not compile.

Comment: I've just compiled, as you can guess. I've  copy-pasted the code again in case I had a bad copy previously.  When you have a moment, could you compile this updated code, and if it doesn't work, tell me what the log says? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is perfect. There is not any mistake using my recent version of MikTeX.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
\text { epi AV@R }_{\alpha}^{\lambda}= \\
\left\{\begin{array}{l|l}
{\left[\begin{array}{l}
    X \\
    a
    \end{array}\right] \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}} & \begin{array}{l}
\exists y_{1} \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^{n}, y_{2} \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^{n}, \\
y_{3} \in \mathbb{R}: y_{1}-y_{2}+y_{3} 1_{n}^{\top}=X \\
\lambda^{\prime} \pi^{\top} y_{1}-\lambda \pi^{\top} y_{2}+y_{3} \leq a
\end{array}
\end{array}\right\}
\end{array}
\end{equation}
```

[image: outout]

See the latex tutorial on [WP Galaxy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XITuawXZtuQ&list=PLaV8fSkhw35BIlebZmEs6-GsNsBRZxlmH)

Comment: I have removed an irrelevant link from the answer: self-promotion links should be limited to those which are strictly on-topic for the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here I add my proposal with a combination of:

1. `smallmatrix`;
2. `braket` package for to have the `\Set{...}` command.
3. Use of the enviroment `aligned`.

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{braket}
\newenvironment{lsm}
  {\left[\begin{smallmatrix}}
  {\end{smallmatrix}\right]}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \text{epi AV@R}_{\alpha}^{\lambda}=\Set{\begin{lsm} X\\ a\end{lsm}\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\, |\mkern5mu \begin{aligned}
  &\exists y_{1} \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^{n}, y_{2} \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^{n},&\\[-.1em]
  &y_{3} \in \mathbb{R} : y_{1}-y_{2}+y_{3} 1_{n}^{\top}=X&\\[-.3em]
  &\lambda' \pi^{\top} y_{1}-\lambda \pi^{\top} y_{2}+y_{3} \leq a &
\end{aligned}},
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]